# What's the primary phase of the elections?

Tags: support, election

Nominations finished a few hours ago. Now https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election lands immediately on the "election" tab and we can vote already.

The election page says

> Every election has three phases:
>
> 1. Nomination
> 2. Primary
> 3. Election

What's the "primary phase" of the election? Was it skipped on purpose (for example, because the nomination phase was extended), or is this another of the hiccups with our elections? (in which case I'm sorry to be the one to point it out...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click over to [the nomination phase tab](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination), the right-hand side says:

> After 6 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to the primary phase. **However, if there are 10 or fewer candidates, we skip directly to the election phase.**

The primary phase narrows the candidate list down to 10 candidates or less.  We've only got 5, so the primary phase was skipped.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you! First time for me =)